# VBA compiles , and ; inconsistently,

Tags: excel, vba, windows

Hi I’m using a Swedish version of Windows and in excel that means formulas are separated by “;” a semicolon. The VBA editor has always been using an ordinar “,” colon though.

For some reason the VBA editor has started to switch between the colon and semicolon resulting in problems running the code. The switch appear to be random for me and can differ from each time I open a workbook. But not while it’s open.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of the use *in VBA* that switches?

Comment: It is Range(“namedRange1, namedRange2”)
@Rory

Comment: I don't see how that could give a **compile** error when it's a string literal.

Comment: When adding formulas (though your example doesn't seem to be one) via VBA  using the `Formula` property, all formulas should use the "US" comma delimiter.  If you use `FormulaLocal` then you would use your local delimiter `;`